# Does a subclass that seemingly used no base class functionality smell? (Some quirks exist in base class)

Tags: objective-c, reflection

I have an Objective-C library that have numerous classes inheriting a common base class, while they use no functionality from the base class. (Or be specific, they all have no app arrant code beyond an interface definition.)

However in the base class, I made heavy use of reflection that it will perform the tasks of the missing method implementations in its subclasses, based on whatever interface information I can extract from the subclass. This essentially turned its subclasses' source files into configure files that can get compiled with an Objective-C compiler and linked into a binary.

And the library of empty class is written by someone in our team that does not understand Objective-C.

So I am thinking, does this code smell? Or is it a brilliant design?

#### EDIT

The subclasses are essentially empty, have only interface declarations and no real code. Meanwhile the base class leverage the runtime to get the information to do things including:

- Serialize subclasses into and deserialize them from JSON data based on Objective-C property introspection and KVC. Subclass may contain hints to make sure everything is correctly typed.
- Communicate with a server based on the method called on the subclass with automatic serialization and deserialization.

For example:

```
@interface CGIDemoRequest : CGIRemoteObject
@property NSString *name;
- (id)hello
@end // This is it. Implementation of this class is empty.
```

and when you use:

```
{
    // ...
    [[CGIRemoteConnection defaultConnection] setAddressPattern:@"http://www.example.com/api/%@.cgi"];
    // ...
    CGIDemoRequest *req = [CGIDemoRequest new];
    req.name = @"John Doe";
    id resp = [req hello];
    // ...
}
```

the `[req hello]` call will cause the base class to serialize the `req` object into JSON: `{"name": "John Doe"}`, POST to a remote address http://www.example.com/api/Hello.cgi, get the response, and deserialize the response back into an object, returning it into `resp`.

Comment: Rule of thumb : if the phrase "SubClass _is a_ SuperClass" makes sense, then your inheritance makes sense (eg. "Cat _is an_ Animal" makes sense but "Dog _is a_ Cat" makes none). In your case its a bit more complex than that, but seeing as your child class makes no use of its super class, I'd say inheritance is not the right pattern for the job.

Comment: Well my child class make no apparent (direct) use but lots of under-the-hood logic involving some dark magic interaction with libobjc is involved and everytime a child class method is called the base class is informed. @GuillaumeA

Comment: The real question you should ask yourself imho is "will I be able to make a change / fix a bug on these classes in two months without banging my head on the wall". :)

Comment: If I hit a bug I just go ahead and fix the base class and everything will work right out - subclasses, as shown in my example, have no effective code at all. @GuillaumeA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code smell.  A brilliant, brilliant, bit of code smell.

Specifically, smells like you've invented your own runtime + base class on top of the existing runtime and base class (NSObject).

If it works (and works well, doesn't cost you more time than a traditional implementation, etc..) then run with it.   The risk is that it'll end up slowing down development and/or be extremely difficult to refactor to take advantage of system APIs or as the over-arching feature set of your app(s) evolve.

Mantra:  *The best performing application is most often the one that ships first.*

Note that there is a distinct instance of this in the System APIs.   Core Data's NSManagedObject is exactly a class that provides a set of base functionality that then configures subclasses via configuration information stored in the managed object model.

Finally, such an exercise is incredibly valuable for learning the subtleties of Objective-C and OO design patterns.

Comment: It worked and cost less time and line of code to do what it used to do. (Not to mention I can outsource the server API interfacing to whoever wrote that API no matter he understands Objective-C or not, since the "source files" are merely configure files that can be compiled as Objective-C now.)

Comment: Then run with it.   Not all smells are bad. :)

Comment: Thanks. :) My code actually read the metadata of the subclass itself as its configure data - the "subclasses" are really configure files that get parsed by compiler into metadata in the binary and then read by the base class using reflection, and can get `#import`ed into apps that use it. I di not use MOM.